# Run code once after each boot on Android

Tags: android

I need some initialization code to run exactly once, as soon as possible after each reboot, and then never again while the device is running.

- Storing a SharedPreference that indicates the code has run isn't suitable because it survives reboot.
- Relying on `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` to clear a SharedPreference value is not good enough because there are times when this wouldn't be sent (e.g. battery removed).
- Using a static field to indicate the code has run isn't suitable because it would be reset if my app is killed.
- Using some initialization code in my Application class isn't suitable because this would run again if my app is killed.
- Receiving `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is almost good enough, but this can be preceded by other broadcasts my app responds to (such as `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED`) and can be fired after I have already launched my app from the launcher. I need this one-time setup code to run before then.
- I can't rely on `System.currentTimeMillis` to calculate the boot time because clock changes would change the apparent boot time.

One option would be to get the last boot time of the device and see if this has changed (`System.elapsedTime()` is not good enough). I have tried executing commands like `who -b` and `last reboot` but permission is denied for both.

Another option is to store a setting/preference somewhere it will get reset ONLY if the device is rebooted, but not if my app is killed.

Is there another option, or a way to implement one of the above?

Comment: Could you please, perephrase, why can't you just use ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED?

Comment: I think `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is your best bet. If your app receives any other broadcasts before that, such as `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED`, you can queue the necessary tasks to run after whatever initialization needs to be done upon receiving the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but unfortunately it's important to run the code at the first opportunity, which is usually before ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is sent.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey You could run the initialization on the very first broadcast your app receives, regardless of the action, but there again you have the problem of determining last boot. However, that early in the boot process, the only thing that's going to start your app is a system broadcast.

Comment: It seems that isn't guaranteed. I'm able to open apps from the launcher up to 20 seconds before the boot complete event is received. I'll set up a receiver for ACTION_USER_PRESENT as well - that will help.

Comment: Sorry, bad phrasing. I meant that "as early as possible" would probably have to rely on some system broadcast, not necessarily the boot broadcast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a solution to this that seems reliable and meets my requirements. I read the contents of the file `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id`, which gives a unique boot identifier reset every time the device is rebooted.

By reading this file and comparing the value to one stored in SharedPreferences, I can reliably determine whether the device has been rebooted since the last time I ran my initialisation code, without depending on the device clock. This works in all user profiles as they all have their own SharedPreferences.

The advantage of this approach is that I can check for a change whenever I receive any broadcast and when my app starts, so I can run the initialisation regardless of what happens first and even if the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is delayed or missed (common on slow devices).

Unfortunately none of the other answers provided a reliable way to do this, but Hardik Chauhan's intent filter priority tip was useful, because I receive ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED much earlier with that set.

Answer (score 9):

So You want to run you code at the System startup before any other app execution starts right?

If yes than here's the idea,
Create a receiver for the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED and give the priority to 999 which is the highest so this will fire always at first when device gets starts.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I'm trying it and I'm not sure it's making a difference but I'll keep experimenting. Sadly this won't help me work out whether there's been a reboot since the last time the code ran.

Comment: This did seem to make a difference on an older and slower device, thanks! Instead of waiting up to a minute for ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED it was sent quicker than I could launch my app.

Comment: What if two receivers have the same highest priority 999?

Comment: Than it will executes in order that both are defined.
Means the first defined receiver will listen to event first and so on.

Answer (score 3):

1. Listen for `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` as you're doing, along with other broadcasts.
2. I believe Android will instantiate and call `onCreate` of your `Application` class, if you have specified one in your AndroidManifest.xml, prior to calling **any** of your receivers, so by sticking the code in there you'll cover all cases.
3. Or, without an `Application` class, stick the code below in each of your individual `BroadcastReceivers`.

Use this to detect if this is a unique boot:

```
public static boolean hasRunSinceBoot(Context context) {
    long bootTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getLong("last_boot_time", 0) == bootTime) {
        return true;
    }
    prefs.edit().putLong("last_boot_time", bootTime).apply();
    return false;
}
```

then run something like:

```
if (!hasRunSinceBoot(context)) {
    //do whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: Using the Application class won't work because the same code would be called again if the process is killed. Anything relying on System.currentTimeMillis can be fooled by the user changing their clock, or NTP doing this in the background.

Comment: It's fine for the code to be called more than once, that's why it returns true OR false. :)

Comment: Yep, but changing the time on the device changes the apparent boot time, so it would look like a reboot to this code.

Comment: True, that's hard to work around. You could build in a 5 minute fuzz-factor for NTP changes, and depend on a server-based time if you really want to be safe.

Comment: Actually, setting up server based time is the reason for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Catch for `ACTION_USER_INITIALIZE` this will do the job.

If multiple users are logging into while runtime, make sure you catch only the first one. It should be an ease to have a workarround managing that.

An example would be that you store the acknowledge of the start of your process in a SharedPreference, and mandatory delete it when the system is shutting down.

It may no be the most elegant way, but you'll read you destination.

Check the description!!
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_INITIALIZE

> [...](This will not be seen by third party applications because a
>   newly initialized user does not have any third party applications
>   installed for it.) This is sent early in starting the user, around the
>   time the home app is started, before ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is
>   sent.[...]

Unfortunately this is just available for system apps; on secured systems.
May you can find a workarround.

But this is what you need in chronological flow.

If this really does not work in any way.

Do a quality check on  `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` that you really catch it just a single time.

I think a service catching `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` and saving its arrival for the first time. So every time `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is to be caught again, you just check if its the fist time.

Same here, when booting off, you also should reset the flag we've set just in before.

If really everything mentioned up here does not work.

Fetch `/proc/uptime`
so you can handle it that way. No permissions needed.

Comment: ACTION_USER_INITIALIZE isn't available. For the reasons I've described above, ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is not suitable because apps can be opened before this is sent, and I need to run this code before any apps are opened. /proc/uptime is similar to System.elapsedTime - you can't reliably use it to determine if the phone has rebooted since the code last ran.